# Can bash_history save evaluated commands output?

Tags: bash, command-history, command-substitution

Is there a way for bash or other shells' history to save the output of evaluated commands when it's a parameter?

```bash
$ echo $(pwd) && history
 /root
 0  I want something like:
 1  echo $(pwd) && history
 2  echo /root && history
```

VS

```bash
$ echo $(pwd) && history
 /root
 0  echo $(pwd) && history
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in ZSH though is problematic (see below) so should not be used:

```
zshaddhistory() {
    local cmd newcmd
    cmd=${1%%$'\n'}
    newcmd=${(e)cmd}
    if [[ $newcmd != $cmd ]]; then
        print -sr -- $cmd
        print -sr -- $newcmd
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
```

Basically we remove the implicit newline from the potential history
addition, then `e` expand the command into a new string. If that caused
something to happen, a custom history addition is performed for the
original and new command; otherwise, the regular history mechanism (via
`return 0`) adds the command to the history.

However! This solution is problematic if any of the expanded `$(...)` have side-effects, a similar problem to C or LISP macro code being run twice. So, I would not really recommend it for production use, unless you like debugging problems such as a simple counter going awry:

```
% i=0
% print $((i++))
1
% print $((i++))
3
% print $((i++))
5
% print $((i++))
7
```

Or multiple writes to an output file, etc.

Comment: I'm assuming then it can't be done with bash?

Comment: maybe, but it might require a very long look at the bash manual to figure out